# Running batch file from Java registered as Windows Service using Procrun

Tags: java, batch-file

I have a sample Java application that I registered as a service using [Procrun](http://commons.apache.org/daemon/procrun.html). I am trying to execute Batch file from my application

```
public class Service {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, InterruptedException {       
        if(args.length>0){
            if(args[0].equals("start")){
                ProcessBuilder builder = new 
                    ProcessBuilder("cmd","/c","start","Start.bat");
                builder.start();                
            }else if(args[0].equals("shutdown")){
                ProcessBuilder builder = new 
                    ProcessBuilder("cmd","/c","start","Stop.bat");
                builder.start();                    
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

When I am starting the service, it gets started successfully but it does not launch batch file on my Windows 7.

Contents of Batch files are given below

Start.bat

```
@echo off
echo I am started
pause
```

Please let me know what am I missing here

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried following

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start Start.bat");
```

Answer (score 0):

To execute batch file from java application, try this piece of code:

// "D://bin/" is the location of my .bat

```
   File dir = new File("D:/bin/");
try {

    // sign.bat if my actual file.
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c sign.bat", null, dir);   
      try {

        Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I'm executing a batch file via java `processBuilder`, it always output following in my logger and didn't execute my batch file.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.2652]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

then gave a try with PowerShell and it worked. I used [zt-exec](https://github.com/zeroturnaround/zt-exec) instead of `processBuilder` as it can handle output with logger

sample working code;

```
 new ProcessExecutor()
    .command("powershell", "C:\\Users\\myScript.bat")
    .redirectOutput(Slf4jStream.of(getClass()).asDebug())
    .redirectError(Slf4jStream.of(getClass()).asError())
    .readOutput(true)
    .timeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .destroyOnExit()
    .execute();
```