# Java: Running batch file with ProcessBuilder when app is registered as Windows Service using Procrun

Tags: java, windows-services, processbuilder, procrun

## There is already a 7 year old question with similar title but no accepted answer, hence reposting as my question has additional details.

7 year old question:
 [Running batch file from Java registered as Windows Service using Procrun](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6951615/running-batch-file-from-java-registered-as-windows-service-using-procrun)

**My question:**

I have following java class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(new String[] {"C:\\Work\\test.bat"});
    processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);   
    Process process = processBuilder.start();
    int exitVal = process.waitFor();
}
```

when this is run directly from eclipse, `test.bat` is successfully executed.
However, when it is run from service, `test.bat` does not get executed.

I have installed the jar as a windows service using procrun. Also to validate whether service is correctly installed. I did this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try {
            DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            File file = new File("C:\\Work\\temp.txt");
            FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file, "hello world "+formatter.format(calendar.getTime()), "UTF-8", false);         
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

and this block of code gets executed from service without any problem. It's just that test.bat does not get executed.

Is `ProcessBuilder` not allowed from procrun?

**EDIT**

My `test.bat` :

`start "" cmd /c "echo Hello world!&echo(&pause"`

Comment: i had the same problem and found a solution. i have added it on the original  thread> https://stackoverflow.com/a/77757118/6771708

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that test.bat is not being executed? Please confirm in Task Manager. Be sure to show processes from all users as your batch file will probably be running in the system account.

Note that your batch file will be launched in the [isolated Session 0](https://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html#WhatIsSession0Isolation) and you will not be able to see the command window (and you won't be able to respond to the "pause" command"). You should consider this restriction as you graduate from your test to something real/useful...

Comment: is there any way to run a gui based application from the windows service? For e.g. I tried opening browser / explorer from the bat file , but they do not show up when service calls this batch file (they do show up when bat file is called directly)

Comment: Session 0 did clarify a lot of doubts. One option to run GUI based apps as service is YAJSP (http://yajsw.sourceforge.net/#mozTocId210483)

Comment: GUI applications generally run fine in Session 0 -- you just can't see or interact with them from a regular login session (Session 1, 2, etc.). This is a fundamental restriction built into the operating system and all the service wrappers (including YAJSP) have to contend with it.

Comment: Yes, but in my case I need a way to provide an interactive GUI. Any pointers?